# Alarmmanager goes off immediately

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, alarmmanager

I'm currently working on an AlarmClock in AndroidStudio. My project works totally fine on my Emulator, meaning that when I choose a time from my TimePicker, the alarm goes off at that chosen time, which is excatly how it's supposed to be. However, if I run the application on my real Android phone, the alarm goes off immediately and does not take my TimePicker into account, at all.
Maybe someone can tell me what's wrong, since it works on the emulator but not on my real phone?
I read somewhere that it could have something todo with the "alarmmanager.set" in which I have chosen "calendar.getTimeInMillis()". But I'm confused as to what it shold be instead and why it works on my emulator but not on my real phone.
Please help a noob in trouble!

Here is the main Class:

```
public class SleepActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


AlarmManager alarmmanager;
TimePicker alarmtimepicker;


PendingIntent pendingintent;



private SleepRepository sp;
private Date date;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {





    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sleep);
    sp = new SleepRepository(SleepActivity.this);
    date = new Date();


    //Create an Intent to the Receiver Class
    final Intent receiver = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);

    alarmmanager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    alarmtimepicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.sleep_timepicker);
    alarmtimepicker.setIs24HourView(true);









    // Initializing the two Buttons in activity_sleep.xml
    Button startsleep = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sleep_startlog_button);
    Button endsleep = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sleep_endlog_button);

    final SleepRepository database = new SleepRepository(SleepActivity.this);
    final Date date = new Date();


    List<Sleep> sleepList = database.getAllRecords();
    Log.v("MOINMOINMOIN", "HALLO HALLO HALLO");
    Log.v("SleepActivity", sleepList.toString());


            // onClickListener for the two Buttons in activity_sleep.xml
            startsleep.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    database.insertRecord(33.0, date, 33);




                    //Setting Calendar instance with the Hour and Minute that we have picked on the TimePicker
                    int currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                    if (currentApiVersion > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1){
                        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmtimepicker.getHour());
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmtimepicker.getMinute());


                    } else {
                        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmtimepicker.getCurrentHour());
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmtimepicker.getCurrentHour());

                    }








                    //Put in extra String into Receiver Intent
                    //Tells the Clock that you have pressed the "Go to Bed" button
                    receiver.putExtra("extra", "alarm on");

                    //Create a pending Intent that delays the Intent until the specified Calendar-Time
                    pendingintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                    //Set the AlarmManager

                    alarmmanager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingintent);



                }
            });





    endsleep.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            //Put in extra String into Receiver Intent
            //Tells the clock that you have pressed the "Wake Up" button
            receiver.putExtra("extra", "alarm off");


            //Stop the Ringtone
            sendBroadcast(receiver);

            alarmmanager.cancel(pendingintent);


        }
    });
```

Here is my BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.e("We are in the Receiver!", "yay");


    //fetch extra Strings from intent
    String get_your_string = intent.getExtras().getString("extra");


    Log.e("What is the key??", get_your_string);


    //Create an Intent for the RingtoneService
    Intent service_intent = new Intent(context, RingtoneService.class);


    //pass the extra Strings from SleepActivity to the Ringtone Playing Service
    service_intent.putExtra("extra", get_your_string);


    //Start the Ringtone Service
    context.startService(service_intent);

}
```

}

and finally my RingtoneService which tells the media player to play a ringtone:

```
public class RingtoneService extends Service {

MediaPlayer media;
String message;
boolean isRunning;


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Log.i("LocalService", "Receive start id" + startId + ":" + intent);


    //fetch the extra String Values
    String state = intent.getExtras().getString("extra");


    // assert = If there is a "NullPointerException", then do not go through the code below

    Log.e("Ringtone extra is", state);

    // assert state != null;
    //this converts the extra Strings from the intent to start ID's, value 0 or 1;

    switch (state) {
        case "alarm on":
            startId = 1;
            break;
        case "alarm off":
            startId = 0;
            break;
        default:
            startId = 0;
            break;
    }





    // if else - statements to either start or stop the ringtone

    //if there is no music playing, and the user pressed "Go to Sleep"
    //Music should start playing.
    if (!this.isRunning && startId == 1) {

        Log.e("there is no music", "and it should play");

        //Create an Instance of the MediaPlayer and start it
        media = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ringtone);
        media.start();

        this.isRunning = true;
        startId = 0;

    }

    //if there is music playing, and the user pressed "Wake up"
    //Music should stop playing.
    else if (this.isRunning && startId == 0) {

        Log.e("there is no music", "and it should not play");

        //stop the ringtone
        media.stop();
        media.reset();

        this.isRunning = false;
        startId = 0;


    }


    //these are if the user presses random buttons
    //bug-preventive

    //if there is no music playing, and the user pressed "Wake Up"
    //do nothing.
    else if (!this.isRunning && startId == 0) {

        Log.e("there is no music", "and it should not play");

        this.isRunning = false;
        startId = 0;

    }

    //if there is music playing, and the user pressed "Go to sleep"
    //do nothing.
    else if (this.isRunning && startId == 1) {

        Log.e("there is music", "and it should play");

        this.isRunning = true;
        startId = 1;

    }

    //catch the odd event.
    else {

        Log.e("else", "somehow you reached this");

    }







    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: i think it's related to `currentApiVersion` and the if-statement next to this, maybe it's not working as you expect. a `Log.d()` is good for this to find out what happens, which if-statement got executed, what are the values are changed ... etc. because what appears is `AlarmManager.set()` got called with a value equivalent to `now` which fires the alarm immediately. just to confirm this, the API level of the emulator is not the same as the real device, right?

Comment: That's right. The emulator has API version 23 and my phone has API Version 21. It's just so weird. My friend just testet the app on his actual phone. When he for example sat the time to 1 or 2 minutes before the actual time, the alarm would go off immediately but when he changed the alarm to a whole hour before the actual time, the alarm went of 15 minutes to late.

Comment: to begin with, API level (21 and 23) falls in diferent if-statement, so we have something here can lead us to the issue, i did not get the second part when ur friends set time minutes **before** acutal time? you mean **after** ?

Comment: I really much think that you are right and that it has something to do with the if-else statement. But I kind of have to have it in there because the .getHour() funtion is only available from API 23 and above and withtout the statement, it will crash on my API 21 Android Phone. Therefore I added it, so it checks if the API is above 23, so it will use .getCurrentHour() instead of .getHour(). But if that is the error, I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: I just tried to change ".getHour()" to ".getCurrentHour()" and let it run on the emulator. With that, I get the same error on the emulator as on my real phone, so it has something todo with the ".getCurruntHour()" function.  Is there any function for the API 23 that is similar to ".getHour()"? Or do I just have accept that I cannot run it on my real phone?

Comment: google it, i will google it too, meanwhile can you compare the values of `getCurruntHour()` and `getHour()` ? i mean Log both values below each other, and one more question, why not use `getCurruntHour()` for all API's is it deprecated ?

Comment: I will try to log both and compare them, but I don't know how to do so, since I have to log a string, and I cannot write getHour().toString. And yes, getCurrentHour() is deprecated :(

Comment: just do like this `Log.d(TAG, "value of alarmtimepicker.getCurrentHour()=" + alarmtimepicker.getCurrentHour());` do the same for `getHour()`

Comment: i found that `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` takes 24-hours format, and `Calendar.HOUR` takes 12-hour AM_PM, so you may want to use both of them based on the getXXX() you are using?!

Comment: I found my error. It is pretty embarrissing. As you can see here in my code:

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmtimepicker.getCurrentHour());
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmtimepicker.getCurrentHour());

I wrote .getCurrentHour() two times, for the hours and for the minutes. That's were my error was. Thank you very much for your help buddy.

Comment: opps, i am embarrassed too :(, but i have trusted you :( :P, good to hear that and good luck